# Finding root cause of "The operation has been cancelled due to restrictions"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

BLUF:  What tools/commands can I use to see what the GPO is specifically restricting.

We have a Server 2008 R2 infrastructure with a GPO that makes our Windows 7 PC's a "kiosk" PC for a specific user when logged in.  With that GPO we limited pretty much everything and we only allow specified EXE's to run.  I don't want to use the kiosk Windows 10 mode as it appears you have to get 3rd party apps.  GPO is just easier, usually, to do what we need it to do.

I'm running into the issue, only one Windows 10, of "The operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer."  It pops up about 5 times on startup, autocloses the windows after some time, then popups up 10-15 minutes later.

I've ran Process Monitor and allowed every legitimate EXE that shows is doing something.  I've looked at Startup programs, all of those exe's are allowed.  I've looked in the Event Viewer just to see if anything sticks out and I don't think anything.

Comment: I would not assume it is an executable that is not whitelisted. This could be a result of other policy restrictions.

Comment: Run GPRESULT against the machine/user and see what GPO's are applied. Then go look at those GPO's.

Comment: @joeqwerty there are only 2 GPO's applying, which is correct.  Those GPO's  deny most everything since they're supposed to.  I just can't figure out what, on the machine, is running that's being denied and which part of the GPO is restricting.

Comment: @GregAskew That's where I'm leading, just not sure which policy would be restricting what.  Only thing I can think of disable one thing, apply GPO, and see if error pops back up.  Was hoping for an easier method

Comment: Do you have batch files that start automatically ? Check what they are doing because this error message might appear if one of the batch files tries to do something forbidden.

Comment: @Swisstone Not for that user or computer.

Comment: Ultimately...updating it to Win 10, 1903 stopped the messages from popping up.  We were having issues with windows update on it after a while we using the upgrade assistant and manually updating it has done away with the restrictions message.  Evidently it was some windows update restriction I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately...updating it to Win 10, 1903 stopped the messages from popping up. We were having issues with windows update on it after a while we using the upgrade assistant and manually updating it has done away with the restrictions message. Evidently it was some windows update restriction I assume.